# How to send or post praise in Yammer using the Rest API?

Tags: yammer

Can someone please provide the API to use for creating a praise update in Yammer? I'm using the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out this awesome guide on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), in order for your question to be well received!

Answer (score 2):

Posting Praise messages through the Yammer API is not a supported operation at this time.